# eclipse plugin-IMarkerResolution-How to remove eclipse's own quick fix items from the dropdown list

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I an developing a eclipse plugin, and have a question about Marker Resolution/quick fix. Basically, what I want is to show a marker besides some line of code and highlight it, and if the user clicks the marker, it will show a drop-down list, providing some predefined items for users to click. I did that by extending org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerResolution, creating MarkerResolutionGenerator classes by extending IMarkerResolutionGenerator, and MarkerResolution Classes by extending IMarkerResolutionGenerator2, IMarkerResolution, IMarkerResolution2.

But it turns out that there are some eclipse's own items in the list, such as "extract it to a local variable". I want to know how to remove those eclipse's own items?

Additional information is if I hover over the highlighted line of code, it will also show a list, which does not contain eclipse's own items. But hover over is not what I want.

Or is there any other ways/APIs that can achieve the function I want?

any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you!

Joey

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove any existing quick fixes, that can be done via [Equinox Transforms](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Transforms). The hover messages are a lot more difficult, as these are *not* controlled via an extension point for the Java editor.